# Xubuntu 12.10 cannot archive folder on desktop

Tags: xubuntu, archive, thunar, .desktop

When I right click a folder on the desktop, there's no option to archive it. I actually have to open up the Thunar file manager, navigate to the desktop folder, and right click on the folder in order to archive it. Why can't I archive directly from the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

**thunar-archive-plugin**

Do you have a default archive manager installed and set to correctly archive?

[image]

The standard MIME association mechanism is used to determine the preferred archive manager for the `Create Archive…`, `Extract Here` and `Extract To…` actions. However the plugin may not always be able to detect the appropriate archive manager for a certain task. Then the user will need to manually select the preferred archive manager from a list of possible applications.

See [THIS PAGE](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/thunar-plugins/thunar-archive-plugin) for the tutorial.

There are some other [plug-ins here](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/thunar-plugins/start).

Comment: I only have one archiver installed, that is Archive Manager, so I don't think there is a problem with determining the preferred archiver.